# com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7 library not present in java IText

Tags: java, itext

No matter what version of IText I add to my project

```
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7
```

is nerver there.

Although there is reference to that in javadoc
http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPKCS7.html

Could someone please tell me why I am not able to add com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7?

P.S.: Have tried all versions from 5.3.0 to 5.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PdfPKCS7 has the following package signature

```
package com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security;
```

and also has an alternative javadoc page http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/security/PdfPKCS7.html

It is probably an automatic build of a snapshot that mixes the javadocs.

Comment: Thanks! You made me realize we don't throw away our old files when building the API documentation. This is the correct API doc: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/security/PdfPKCS7.html I'll see what I can do about removing legacy pages.

Comment: The script that makes the API docs now throws away the old HTML pages. Thanks again.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie glad that somewhat helped an open source project by stackoverflow